# When should I use GL_TRUE or GL_FALSE values?

Tags: opengl, c++

When using `GLboolean`, should I just use `true` and `false` or should I use `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE`? When should I prefer using `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE`? or maybe I shouldn't care at all (Because both works)?

[Here](https://github.com/haskell-opengl/OpenGLRaw/issues/15) It is said that both are actually a different type.

But in some tutorial websites I've read, they use `GL_TRUE` or `GL_FALSE` on functions that requires `GLboolean`. Example:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
```

Well, it works too if we substitute `GL_FALSE` with `false` in the code above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's only a matter of opinion and code style. You can use:

- `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE`
- `true` and `false`
- `1` and `0`
- Or anything that can be converted to 1 and 0.

They all may have different types, but usually it does not matter because they all will be implicitly converted to `GLboolean` upon use.

Use whatever you want, any of them will work.

My only advice would be to choose *one* style and maintain the consistent usage of it across your code.

Answer (score 2):

Those macros were created because C didn't have a true/false keyword like C++ does.

In C using `GL_TRUE` and `GL_FALSE` made the code easier to read compared to using just 0 and 1 so it was provided by the OpenGL headers.

In C++ you may as well use the builtin keywords `true` and `false` and enjoy your favorite IDE's highlighting feature. Or you may use OpenGL's macro to be consistent with OpenGL code.

- `GL_TRUE` is 1 and `GL_FALSE` is 0.
- C++'s `true` is also 1 and `false` is also 0.

It's guaranteed to work.

For portability however you must still use `GLboolean` and not `bool` for any GL functions demanding a **pointer** to `GLboolean` (such as `glGetBooleanv`) even if they happen to be the same size on current platforms. That may not be the case in the future.

But assigning `GLboolean b = true;` is perfectly safe.

---

To answer the comment on explicitly comparing to `GL_TRUE`/`GL_FALSE`:

It's generally a bad idea to compare to `GL_TRUE` or `true` (eg: `if(x == true)`) as this may introduce hard to find bugs (eg: where x is 2). You should use simply `if(x)` as anything other than zero is considered true but may not be equal to `GL_TRUE` or `true` and this may create an inconsistency between what your code thinks is true and OpenGL's interpretation.

`GLboolean` are not `bool` and may (accidentally) contain a value other than 1 or 0. This can cause some confusion and the comparison failing can result in a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) and many hours of debugging down the wrong path when tracing code.

Comparing to `GL_FALSE` or `false` is safe (both `==` and `!=`) as only 0 can be `false`.

So if you wish to use an explicit comparison use `if(x != GL_FALSE)` to consistently compare x to "true".